# ALSA callback (SIGIO handler) hangs sometimes somewhere in boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time()

Tags: c++, audio, boost, alsa

I use ALSA in async mode with callbacks (snd_async_add_pcm_handler()). Every ALSA's callback is called from SIGIO signal handler. Every callback calls my function **getCurrentTimeMs()**:

```
// Return current milliseconds (don't care - local time or UTC).
long long getCurrentTimeMs(void)
{
    std::cout << "+"; std::cout.flush();
    long long ret = 0;

#define Z
#ifdef Z
    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime( CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
    ret = ts.tv_sec * 1000;
    ret += ts.tv_nsec / 1000000;
#else
    boost::posix_time::ptime now = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
    std::cout << "."; std::cout.flush();
    boost::posix_time::ptime    epoch_start(boost::gregorian::date(1970,1,1));
    std::cout << "."; std::cout.flush();
    boost::posix_time::time_duration dur = now - epoch_start;
    std::cout << "."; std::cout.flush();
    ret = dur.total_milliseconds();
#endif
    std::cout << "-"; std::cout.flush();
    return ret;
}
```

Signal handler can be called before previous handler is finished;

i need current time in ms to measure precise samplerate.

If i comment **#define Z**, the boost is used. In "boost mode" application hangs after unpredictable amount of time from audio playing start. **strace** show application hangs on this:

```
    write(1, "+"..., 1)                     = 1
    gettimeofday({1332627252, 660534}, NULL) = 0
    futex(0xb68dba4c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
```

But **0xb68dba4c** occured only 2...3 times in all the trace log. The **futex(0xb68dba4c ...** is not the thing that occurs on every getCurrentTimeMs() call. But when it occurs, everything hangs and it occurs only after that **gettimeofday**; i see "+." on the console and then that **futex** occurs. But before that, application can play tons of sound, calling **getCurrentTimeMs()** on each callback 50 times per second. Such a mystery...

With **#define Z** my code is used. In this case the application works great - playing gigabytes of WAV files with no hangs.

The application has 2 threads running via boost::threadpool and both using the **getCurrentTimeMs()**; lets assume i have some deadlock errors; but i have no idea how **#define Z** may affect that.

**EDIT:**
My question is answered in this way and i accept this answer:
1) http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.alsa.devel/96282
2) http://answerpot.com/showthread.php?3448138-ALSA+async+callback+re-enter+and+DEADLOCK.

Answer (score 1):

If this is what it looks like to me, there are two kinds of asynchronous scheduling to consider: asynchronous threads, and asynchronous interrupts ("signals"). Threads run independent of each other unless they explicitly synchronize; signals are scheduled asynchronously but preempt and block whatever thread they're delivered to. It looks very much like the boost functions or iostreams you're calling achieve thread-safety by locking, which makes them _un_safe to call in an interrupt handler because the thread the handler preempted may very well already hold the lock.

One thing you might do is to arrange to have all signals delivered to a thread that does nothing else -- maybe fire up a thread immediately on startup and have your mainline code run there, leaving the original main thread dedicated to signal handling.

Comment: Thank you! But is it guaranteed that signals will be handled only by main thread? Is main thread is the only thread that is interrupted by signals?

Comment: Hey, sorry I'm late, since you said ALSA you can get linux-specific, I think the easiest is probably on startup block everything and clone() to your inner main() with whatever you want shared, then set the signal mask the way you like.  Then that inner main and anything it creates runs signals-off by default.